# Finding group size

Tags: sql

I have sample [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEU3w.jpg) and need to base on Timing and XY coordinates to indicate the Group size using SQL statements to indicate in an added 'GroupSize' column. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please paste sample data in question and also write the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with group by, you do it like this:

```
Select timing, X, Y, count(*) group_size
From MYTABLE
Group By timing, X, Y
```

If you want to see the group size "added on" to your details. You can use a window function (if you sql engine supports it):

```
Select 
   timing, X, Y, 
   count(*) over (partition by timing, X, Y) group_size
From MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thanks gadaju, tried tested and ok!